# is there a way to pull one record per "group" that has a duplicate price to the others in the same group?

Tags: sql, duplicates, firebird

I'm using Firebird 3.0, and I'm trying to get a single record for a duplicated cost where Manufacturer, Model, Part type is the same

```
Manufacturer | Model | Part Type | Total Price | Rank
Apple|iPhone 6S|LCD & Digitizer Assembly|109|1
Apple|iPhone 6S|LCD & Digitizer Assembly|109|1
Apple|iPhone 6S|LCD & Digitizer Assembly|109|2
Apple|iPhone 6S|LCD & Digitizer Assembly|69|3
Apple|iPhone 6S|LCD & Digitizer Assembly|69|3
Apple|iPhone 6S|LCD & Digitizer Assembly|89|4
Apple|iPhone 6S|LCD & Digitizer Assembly|89|4
Apple|iPhone 6S|LCD & Digitizer Assembly|89|5
Apple|iPhone 6S|LCD & Digitizer Assembly|89|5
Apple|iPhone 6S|LCD & Digitizer Assembly|89|6
Apple|iPhone 6S|LCD & Digitizer Assembly|89|6
```

I cannot get distinct to work in the where clause, I can't use select distinct

This is the query I have so far (I haven't added the needed code to get the records I want):

```
SELECT   "Manufacturer" "Manufacturer", 
         "Model" "Model", 
         "Part Type" "Part Type", 
         "SKU" "SKU", 
         "Total Price" "Total Price", 
         "Color" "Color", 
         "Quality" "Quality", 
         "Rank" "Rank" 
FROM     "vwPopParts" 
WHERE    (
                  "Part Type" = 'LCD & Digitizer Assembly' 
         OR       "Part Type" = 'LCD' 
         OR       "Part Type" = 'Battery' 
         OR       "Part Type" = 'Charging Port' ) 

                  ORDER BY "Manufacturer" ASC, "Model" ASC, "Part Type" ASC, "Rank" ASC
```

I just want one of the highlighted entry to be pulled and the rest of the  non-duplicated prices to show as well.

Update: Figured it out thank you all for helping , ended up doing it in 2 queries

## 1

```sql
SELECT "Manufacturer", 
      "Model", 
      "Part Type", 
      Min("Rank") "Rank", 
      "Total Price" 
FROM   "vwPopParts" 
WHERE  "Part Type" IN ( 'LCD & Digitizer Assembly', 'LCD', 'Battery', 
                       'Charging Port' ) 
GROUP  BY "Manufacturer", 
         "Model", 
         "Part Type", 
         "Total Price" 
ORDER  BY "Manufacturer" ASC, 
         "Model" ASC, 
         "Part Type" ASC
```

## 2

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM   "vwPopParts" 
       NATURAL JOIN "qryPopularItems1"
```

Comment: What results do you want?  What does "duplicated cost" mean?  There is no "cost" in your data.

Comment: Sorry "total price" would be the duplicated value.

Comment: So like if the manufacturer, model and part type are a group and I have multiple of the same total price in that group I want the part with the lowest rank to show

Comment: show sample data u have before the query and results you want to have after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `max()` to get the same effect as `distinct`:

```
SELECT
    "Manufacturer", 
    "Model", 
    "Part Type", 
    "SKU", 
    "Total Price", 
    "Color", 
    "Quality", 
    MIN("Rank")
FROM "vwPopParts"
WHERE "Part Type" IN (
    'LCD & Digitizer Assembly', 'LCD', 'Battery', 'Charging Port'
)
GROUP BY
    "Manufacturer", 
    "Model", 
    "Part Type", 
    "SKU", 
    "Total Price", 
    "Color", 
    "Quality"
ORDER BY "Manufacturer" ASC, "Model" ASC, "Part Type" ASC, "Rank" ASC
```

If this doesn’t work, try grouping by different columns.

Note also the simplification from the big "OR" chain of conditions to a single "IN" condition.

Comment: Thank you for the advice its almost there I think , with firebird I'm kinda forced quote all columns and I think its gonna be a min("Rank") for that

Comment: @aaron I've modified the query to incorporate your feedback. Is it working now?

Comment: @aaronstevenson You are forced to quote columns because you use case sensitive names with spaces in them (and a number of reserved words). You would need to quote in with those names in all database systems.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the rows with the minimum price using:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.price = (select min(t2.price)
                 from t t2
                 where t2.Manufacturer = t.Manufacturer and
                       t2.Model = t.Model and
                       t2.Parttype = t.Parttype
                );
```

You can get a single row using:

```
select distinct t.Manufacturer, t.Model, t.Parttype, t.price
from t
where t.price = (select min(t2.price)
                 from t t2
                 where t2.Manufacturer = t.Manufacturer and
                       t2.Model = t.Model and
                       t2.Parttype = t.Parttype
                );
```

Or using some other method, particularly if you're data has a unique key identifying each row.